# The difference between asyncpg and psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, asyncpg

Why does the `asyncpg` library exist in python if **PostgreSQL** already supports many simultaneous connections at once? Can anyone explain the difference, and in which cases which library should be used?

> It's just important for me to find out the difference, since I plan to create discord bots where there are a lot of `async` functions, and if `psycopg2` blocks the script like `time.sleep()` does in the `async` function, then it won't suit me.

Comment: 1) AFAIK `asyncpg` has nothing to do with `psycopg2`, it is a completely different project. 2) `psycopg2` has a [async support](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#async-support). Read the information at the link. 3) The new version of `psycopg` also has [async support](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/async.html). Again read the information at the link.

Comment: `asyncpg` developer showed the benchmark results of how fast his library works in comparrison to `psycopg2` - it's **3** times faster. Why do people still use it then?

Comment: 1)  `asyncpg` does not support Python DB-API. 2) The benchmark is from the same author. 3) The benchmark is ~2 1/2 years old and does not include `psycopg(3)`. 4) If you are not trying to move 2,200,000 rows/sec does it matter? 5) `psycopg2` has a history of being reliable. Not saying `asyncpg` is unreliable, just if you have a driver that works and delivers the performance you need why change? Most of the time the perceived time to the end user is coming from something higher in the stack, generally the display code.

Comment: Well, alrighty. I'm just trying to figure out what to learn, that why the question came. I've made my decisions, thanks for helping me figure out what's the difference between those 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the asyncpg library exist in python if

Libraries exist because someone felt like writing them.  There is no one in charge of telling people they aren't allowed to write new libraries if they want to.  So the existence is not evidence of the necessity.  But...

> PostgreSQL already supports many simultaneous connections at once?

But, how do you make use of that?  The main methods of psycopg2 are blocking.  When you dispatch a query, it blocks until the results are ready and fetched.  You can have another connection open, but you can't easily get control back in order to do something with that other connection.  There are ways around this limitation but they were bolted on as an after thought, while asyncpg provides nicer ways more consistent with how other async programming works in python (in theory, anyway)